A tokusatsu show where they capture monsters via card
The tokusatsu show maybe outside Japan I think Chinese or Korean but I could be mistaken. I remember one episode on YouTube where the main team gets replaced by a other temporary team I believe. And other fact is they transform and use a card to capture a monster after that one of them holds the card near his belt where the card is transported to a void where it transform into a gemstone. (Not SPD)

Please help me with this one.it is my first request on the website
